# Script features slow when you have a lot of data

Tags: php, mysql

The code below is a social networking script is the class of the feed, the problem when the fees have many posts and many the followers even apresetnta a giant slow, someone could tell me if there is something wrong with the queries and the script below , thank you

```
public function __construct($dbo = NULL)
{
    parent::__construct($dbo);
}

public function count()
{
    $count = 0;

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM profile_followers WHERE follower = (:followerId) ORDER BY create_at DESC");
    $stmt->bindParam(':followerId', $this->requestFrom, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

            $stmt2 = $this->db->prepare("SELECT count(*) FROM posts WHERE fromUserId = (:fromUserId) AND removeAt = 0 ORDER BY createAt DESC");
            $stmt2->bindParam(':fromUserId', $row['follow_to'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt2->execute();

            $count = $count + $stmt2->fetchColumn();
        }
    }

    return $count;
}

public function getMaxId()
{
    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT MAX(id) FROM posts");
    $stmt->execute();

    return $number_of_rows = $stmt->fetchColumn();
}

public function get($itemId = 0)
{
    if ($itemId == 0) {

        $itemId = $this->getMaxId();
        $itemId++;
    }

    $feed = array("error" => false,
                  "error_code" => ERROR_SUCCESS,
                  "itemId" => $itemId,
                  "items" => array());

    $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM profile_followers WHERE follower = (:followerId) ORDER BY create_at DESC");
    $stmt->bindParam(':followerId', $this->requestFrom, PDO::PARAM_INT);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {

        $items = array();

        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) {

            $stmt2 = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id FROM posts WHERE fromUserId = (:fromUserId) AND id < (:itemId) AND removeAt = 0 ORDER BY id DESC");
            $stmt2->bindParam(':fromUserId', $row['follow_to'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt2->bindParam(':itemId', $itemId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $stmt2->execute();

            while ($row2 = $stmt2->fetch())  {

                $items[] = array("id" => $row2['id'], "itemId" => $row2['id']);
            }
        }

        $stmt3 = $this->db->prepare("SELECT id FROM posts WHERE fromUserId = (:fromUserId) AND id < (:itemId) AND removeAt = 0 ORDER BY id DESC");
        $stmt3->bindParam(':fromUserId', $this->requestFrom, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt3->bindParam(':itemId', $itemId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt3->execute();

        while ($row3 = $stmt3->fetch())  {

            $items[] = array("id" => $row3['id'], "itemId" => $row3['id']);
        }

        $currentItem = 0;
        $maxItem = 20;

        if (count($items) != 0) {

            arsort($items);

            foreach ($items as $key => $value) {

                if ($currentItem < $maxItem) {

                    $currentItem++;

                    $item = new post($this->db);
                    $item->setRequestFrom($this->requestFrom);

                    $itemInfo = $item->info($value['itemId']);

                    array_push($feed['items'], $itemInfo);

                    $feed['itemId'] = $itemInfo['id'];

                    unset($itemInfo);
                    unset($item);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return $feed;
}

public function setRequestFrom($requestFrom)
{
    $this->requestFrom = $requestFrom;
}

public function getRequestFrom()
{
    return $this->requestFrom;
}`
```

Comment: SO is not a code reviewing service

Comment: Try asking on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Perhaps you should consider using a single query with a JOIN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions in general:

- instead of "SELECT *", use "SELECT follow_to" since that is the only
  column you use
- on the same statement, sorting takes time and is not used
- there is no need to execute a new query for every profile_follower
- on the inner query, there is no need to sort just to get a count

If there are 1,000 followers, you are sorting the posts 1,000 times unnecessarily.

Instead, use one query and index posts on id and removeAt and index profile_followers on follower.

```
SELECT  count(*) 
FROM    posts p
JOIN    profile_followers pf ON p.fromUserId = pf.follow_to
WHERE   p.removeAt = 0
AND     pf.follower = :followerId;
```